# In Ajax post method in success part the posting sequence of data and get sequence of data is diff

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In my given code i have created dynamically textbox with diff ids and in javascript is have fetch  value of textbox one by one till here all things are perfect but when i pass this data from ajax post method to other file the sequence of fetched data will change

---

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var i = $('input').size() + 1;
 $('#add').click(function() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;

    $('<div id="d"><input type="text" id="field'+value+'" name="dynamic[]" value="' + i + '" /><br/><input type="text" class="field1" name="dynamic1[]" value="' + i+i + '" /></div> ').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs'); 
    i++;
});

$('#remove').click(function() {
if(i > 1) {
    $('.field:last').remove();
    $('.field1:last').remove();
    i--; 
}
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
while(i > 2) {
    $('.field:last').remove();
    $('.field1:last').remove();
    i--;
}
}); 
$('.submit').click(function(){                              
var number = document.getElementById("number").value; 
for(var i=1;i<=number;i++)
{        
        answers = $('#field'+i).val(); 
        alert(answers);
        $.ajax({     
                   type: "POST",
                   url: " dd.php",
                   data: {answers:answers},
                   cache: false,
                   success: function(html)
                   {                                 
                           alert(html);                              
                   }
                })
  }
   return false;                        
   });
});
</script>
<style>
.field{
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 5px 24px 78px;
}
.field1{
  padding:0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 5px 24px 78px;
}
#d{
  display:flex;
}

.submit{
width:110px;
background-color:#FF6;
padding:3px;
border:1px solid #FC0;
margin-top:20px;}   

</style>
<body>
    <div>
     <a href="#" id="add">Add</a> | <a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a>  | <a href="#" id="reset">Reset</a>  
 <form>
    <input type="hidden" id="number" value="0"/>  
    <div class="inputs">    
    </div>
    <input name="submit" type="button" class="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
 </div> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: kindly comment your `#remove`   and     `#click`    jquery functions and then try...

Comment: Nope still not working

Answer (score 1):

The Above code won't work. You missed the class in the first input field, you kept id instead of class name.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var i = $('input').size() + 1;
    $('#add').click(function()
    {
        $('<div class="d"><input type="text" class="field" name="dynamic[]" value="' + i + '" /><br/><input type="text" class="field1" name="dynamic1[]" value="' + i+i + '" /></div> ').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs'); 
        i++;
    });

    $('#remove').click(function() {
    if(i > 1) {
        $('.field:last').remove();
        $('.field1:last').remove();
        i--; 
    }
    });

    $('#reset').click(function() {
    while(i > 2) {
        $('.field:last').remove();
        $('.field1:last').remove();
        i--;
    }
    }); 

    });
    </script>
    <style>
    .field{
    padding:0 0 0 0;
        margin: 0 5px 24px 78px;
    }
    .field1{
    padding:0 0 0 0;
        margin: 0 5px 24px 78px;
     }
    .d{
      display:flex;
    }

    .submit{
    width:110px;
    background-color:#FF6;
    padding:3px;
    border:1px solid #FC0;
    margin-top:20px;
    }   
    </style>
    <body>
    <div>
        <a href="#" id="add">Add</a> | <a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a>  | <a href="#" id="reset">Reset</a>  
    <form method="post" action="dd.php">

        <div class="inputs">    
        </div>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: 1st check my ans i have called php post method by name

Comment: I talk about the script    it wont wont as you called by class for remove and reset. but there is no class in the input field. so its wont work.

Answer (score -2):

After Searching i got ans of my question so i feel to share with all so i posting my ans on my question only.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script> 
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
var i = $('input').size() + 1;
$('#add').click(function()
{
    $('<div id="d"><input type="text" id="field" name="dynamic[]" value="' + i + '" /><br/><input type="text" class="field1" name="dynamic1[]" value="' + i+i + '" /></div> ').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs'); 
    i++;
});

$('#remove').click(function() {
if(i > 1) {
    $('.field:last').remove();
    $('.field1:last').remove();
    i--; 
}
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
while(i > 2) {
    $('.field:last').remove();
    $('.field1:last').remove();
    i--;
}
}); 

});
</script>
<style>
.field{
padding:0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 5px 24px 78px;
}
.field1{
padding:0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 5px 24px 78px;
 }
#d{
  display:flex;
}

.submit{
width:110px;
background-color:#FF6;
padding:3px;
border:1px solid #FC0;
margin-top:20px;
}   
</style>
<body>
<div>
    <a href="#" id="add">Add</a> | <a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a>  | <a href="#" id="reset">Reset</a>  
<form method="post" action="dd.php">

    <div class="inputs">    
    </div>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

---

### dd.php

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST["dynamic"] as $key)
    {
      echo  $key;
    }
?>
```